# How to tie up data (title, date etc) to a list of files I'm retrieving from a folder?

Tags: java, android

I save a list of files into a folder through my app, and when I want to retrieve it, I want to show the Title, date and some other information in each row. How do I tie up these information with each file?

Comment: What do you mean by **data and other information**?

Comment: @user370305 it was a typo. I meant date.

Comment: If you want to date of file then use [lastModified](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#lastModified()) from `File` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create an array. Let's say you are making an app which receives the contact information stored on your device. You can do it a bit like this:

```
TextView phoneNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
TextView contactName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
```

etc...

Then, you can set the arrays in your other activity.

```
String[] contact1;
contact1[0] = "Bob";
contact1[1] = "555-555-5555";
```

If you are planning to use intents, you have to specify which class you are getting your arrays from.
Once you set the arrays and define your TextViews, you can do this:

```
contactName.setText("Name: " + contact1[0])
```

For setting the contacts, you can do this in a loop by setting a number called i and resetting it at the end of each loop. This can shorten your lines of code. You can do the same with setting the value of the TextViews.

If you have further questions, please feel free to reply! I will do what I can to help.

Regards,

Ani

Comment: This will not help me store the data. Once I restart the app, all info will be lost.

Comment: If you plan on storing your data somewhere, I would recommend whatever Fahim said: you should create a database. I believe Google Cloud allows you to do this, but you will have to pay if you are expecting many viewers. I am sorry I could not be of any help. Please let me know if you need a bit of help with Google Cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest storing the date and description for all the list of files in the database.

When you are storing the files in the folder at the same time make an entry in the database for a particular file. Next time you can pick up the details from the database.

Hope this will help you.

Refer this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) to create Sqlite db in android